# CActiveForm beforeValidate is not working with afterValidate

Tags: php, yii

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'reply-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'enableClientValidation' => false,
    'clientOptions' => array(
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        'validateOnChange' => false,
        'beforeValidate' => 'js:function(form){
            alert("before");
        }',
        'afterValidate' => 'js:function(form, data, hasError){
            alert("after");
        }'

    )
));
```

it seems that afterValidate is not working with beforeValidate in CActiveForm,
if I remove beforeValidate, afterValidate is working fine.

Is anyone here know why its working this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just put return true on beforeValidate.